# Dimensions of Pdf file generated by knitR .Rnw latex file too large

Tags: pdf, latex, knitr

I am working on a .Rnw file, mainly latex tables (no plots/figures) that when I compile to a PDF file, the actual dimensions of the pdf when opening under the system pdf viewer (mac) are way too large (the preview of the Rstudio pdf viewer is fine). The file itself is not large (97kb), just the dimension/resolution. This is a problem as I am trying to merge the document with separate pdf files. I cannot figure out to fix this problem. I would guess there are some global settings I need to fix but don't know which exactly.

Comment: Double-check with the canonical "correct" PDF Reader: Acrobat. Check what the *physical size* is, as well as any On-open-zoom-to settings.

Comment: thx. Acrobat automatically shrinks it (20% of actual), but the actual size once reset to 100% is huge. The physical size of the file is not huge, only 97 kb.

Comment: Ah - I meant the size of the document, in cm or in pt or in inches. It sounds as if these are some untypical large values. If you know the output size, you may be able to trace back to where it got set to those numbers.

Comment: Ok. 118.83cm x 83.97cm   which is rather large.

Comment: I should say that the document uses a a0poster class. This could be causing some of the problems, but not sure

Comment: Uh, that is actually quite near the size of A0...  To me this suggests the software is doing what you tell it to, but what you are telling it to do is not what you *want* it to.